# Direction of Mann-Whitney significance test result

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have conducted a Mann-Whitney $U$ test to identify if there is a significant difference in ranking (on Likert scale) of a dependent variable between two groups of people: e.g. those who have <5 year experience and those who have more.

Now I have results, but it only shows that there is a difference in ranking and does  not tell me which group ranking the dependent variable is higher and which lower. Can I check the direction some other way?

Comment: Plot the data, which you should be doing any way. Calculate the medians, indeed also the means even if you don't trust them. A good routine should also be able to show you P(value in group 1 > value in group 2), which is often much more interesting than the P-value.

Comment: Orthodox punctuation and capitalisation make your posts easier to read and make answers more likely.

Comment: I wouldn't use a Mann-Whitney test for Likert scaled data -- you'll get arbitrarily lumpy results as a function of the fact that there are only 5 scale points. Use a simple t-test for mean differences instead. This is pretty much standard applied "best" practice anyway. In addition, you can apply a one-tailed test for directionality of the result.

Comment: @DJohnson Thank you so much, but isn't T test for normal data. my data does not full fill the normality test therefore i choose Mann Whitney U test. How can i apply  the one tailed test for directionality  using SPSS.

Comment: @salma  I understand that your data is ordinally scaled. Having worked with Likert-type attributes for years in applied settings, that issue is considered a wholly academic concern. The heuristic is to assume that these features are "normally distributed" and apply the standard tests.  All of which are quite robust to this kind of "violation," as is the normal distribution in general. Sorry, but I don't have any suggestions wrt SPSS.